# can you save an object array using zarr?

Tags: python, zarr

Following zarr's [tutorial](https://zarr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#object-arrays), I'm trying to save a list of list of ints to a persistent zarr:

- **Failed method 1:**

  ```
  import numcodecs, zarr
  zarr.save("path/to/zarr", [[1], [2]], dtype=object, object_codec=numcodecs.JSON())
  ```
- **Failed method 2:**

  ```
  import numcodec, zarr
  z = zarr.array([[1], [2]], dtype=object, object_codec=numcodecs.JSON())
  zarr.save("path/to/zarr", z, dtype=object, object_codec=numcodecs.JSON())
  ```

Both methods output `ValueError: missing object_codec for object array`

Comment: maybe related to [this](https://github.com/zarr-developers/zarr-python/issues/691) or [this](https://github.com/fsspec/kerchunk/issues/102)

Answer (score 2):

I question why you wouldn't just save your list of ints as an array in Zarr. However, it is generally possible to write object dtypes to zarr arrays:

```
import numpy as np
import zarr
from numcodecs import JSON

# slightly contrived example of an object array
x = np.empty(1, dtype=object)
x[0] = ['foo', 2, 'bar']

za = zarr.open_array('path/to/zarr', shape=x.shape, dtype=object, object_codec=JSON())

print(zarr.open_array(store)[:][0])  # --> ['foo', 2, 'bar']
```